# Isapi Rewrite - access query string pattern matches in RewriteRule

Tags: mod-rewrite, query-string, isapi-rewrite

I'm using Isapi Rewrite 3 (mod rewrite clone for IIS) and trying to rewrite URLs based on the query string - and then pass on part of that query string in the rewrite.

So if I enter a URL like this: **/test/home.cfm?page=default&arbitraryExtraArg=123**

I want that to be rewritten as: **/test/index.cfm?page=home&arbitraryExtraArg=123**

I have the following condition/rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=default(.*)$ [I]
RewriteRule ^/test/home.cfm$ /test/index.cfm?page=home%1 [I,R=301]
```

But the extra query string variables are never passed. %1 seems to be blank.

This is how to reference a pattern match from the RewriteCond, right?

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

EDIT: It looks to me like the RewriteCond is being totally ignored. Here is what my logfile looks like:

```
[snip] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /test/home.cfm?page=default
[snip] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\dev\IsapiRewrite\httpd.conf
[snip] (3) applying pattern '^/test/home\.cfm$' to uri '/test/home.cfm'
[snip] (1) escaping /test/index.cfm?page=home 
[snip] (2) explicitly forcing redirect with http://www.devsite.com/test/index.cfm?page=home
[snip] (2) internal redirect with /test/home.cfm?page=default [INTERNAL REDIRECT]

[snip] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /test/index.cfm?page=home
[snip] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\dev\IsapiRewrite\httpd.conf
[snip] (3) applying pattern '^/test/home\.cfm$' to uri '/test/index.cfm'
```

Should there be mention of the RewriteCond pattern check in there?

Comment: But the rule is applyed?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I end up on /test/index.cfm?page=home

Comment: And what about the initial request of `/test/home.cfm?page=default`? Or are you testing just `/test/index.cfm?page=home` all time long? If so, you probably misunderstood how URL rewriting works. They just rewrite the requested URI!

Comment: Oops! I just included the post-redirect logging. Full log details added now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the extra query string variables are never passed. %1 seems to be blank.

%1 is blank because according to the log the request you make is /test/home.cfm?page=default - without second parameter.

The absense of RewriteCond processing in the log may be due to low RewriteLogLevel.

And the config should be:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=default(.+)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^/test/home.cfm$ /test/index.cfm?page=home%1 [NC,R=301,L]

Comment: Brilliant stuff - thanks man!
Looks like the [I] flag I was setting was causing the whole RewriteCond to be ignored. [I] - for "Ignore case" - was a hangover from IsapiRewrite version 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think ISAPI Rewrite is a little different to mod_rewrite:

> Whenever you put parentheses in any regular expression present in a complex rule (a rule with conditions) you are marking a submatch that could be used in a format string (using `$N` syntax) or as a back-reference (using `\N` syntax) in subsequent conditions. These submathces are global for the whole complex rule (*RewriteRule* directive and corresponding *RewriteCond* directives). Submatches are numbered from up to down and from left to right beginning from the first *RewriteCond* directive (if such directive exists) corresponding to the *RewriteRule*.

So try `$1` to get the match of the first group no matter where it appears:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=default(.*)$ [I]
RewriteRule ^/test/home\.cfm$ /test/index.cfm?page=home$1 [I,R=301]
```

[ISAPI Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) seems to be more compatible to Apache’s mod_rewrite.

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. I'm actually using ISAPI Rewrite 3 - just switched to it yesterday - which is why I'm reworking these rules

Comment: Well then I don’t know why yours doesn’t work. Or is there any other rule that might get in conflict with that one?

Comment: I've removed all other rules except my RewriteLog directive - still no success. I've edited the question above to include the log output - hopefully that can shed some light

Answer (score -1):

I believe this works also:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/home.cfm\?page=default(.*)$ /test/index.cfm?page=home%1 [I,R=301]
```

Comment: That kind of rule worked in ISAPI Rewrite 2 - but ISAPI Rewrite 3 is a clone of Apache mod rewrite. From the mod rewrite site: 
Note: Query String
The Pattern will not be matched against the query string. Instead, you must use a RewriteCond with the %{QUERY_STRING} variable.